# How to return `false` with custom matcher in protractor/jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am using protractor `3.0.0`, and jasmine `1.3.1`.

I am trying to add a custom matcher, but it seems that I can only use it if it returns `true` otherwise my test gets stuck.

This is my custom matcher

```
 toBecomeTrue: function(){
     return browser.sleep(0).then(function(){
         return false;
      });
 },
```

As you can see, I want the test to fail.

However, when I use it

```
it('should ask an SO question', function(){
    browser.get('/');
    expect($$('div')).toBecomeTrue();
});
```

The test gets stuck..

My instinct is that since we are dealing with promises, and since I am returning false.. something is going wrong..

So I am throwing an error instead.. but that does not allow me to use `not`. :(

However, I can't seem to find it documented anywhere, and I am feeling like I am doing something wrong.

Here are a couple of implementations examples I saw and tried but couldn't make it to work

- https://gist.github.com/fpirsch/1790c604a6d54d372a40
- official documentation - see example before upgrade https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/jasmine-upgrade.

Regarding jasmine version, why am I still looking at documentations for 1.3, I have a different question for that.. hope to resolve it soon.

so to recap:

- why does my custom matchers get stuck while following documentations found online?
- is throwing an exception a reasonable solution or is it an unwanted hack?

Answer (score 1):

[Jamine 1.3 is not compatible with protractor version of 3.0.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), From GitHub:

> We're releasing version 3.0 with some breaking changes. In summary - Jasmine 1.3 is removed, only Jasmine 2 is now supported, old Node.JS support is dropped, and plugins now need to be explicitly required. Full details below.

Comment: as you think it worked before? so should I downgrade until I figure out how to get jasmine 2 working?